# How do I adjust handles symmetrically on the same path?

Tags: vector, inkscape, svg

I want to adjust opposite nodes on a path, made from a shape tool, simultaneously to maintain symmetry. For example I make an ellipse, convert the ellipse to a path, then select the two nodes opposite each other and make them symmetric nodes then lengthen one handle by 50% or so, I want the other selected node to do the same. Is there a way to do this?

[image: before]

[image]

Comment: This is a very good question. If Inkscape would ever let users select node handles, or even multiple-select node handles, and then "work" them like nodes (by keyboard, or by numerical entry, etc.) that would make an awesome new feature. Your question about symmetry is just a special case but it shows that lack in Inkscape. I love both answers, which you have triggered (so far). Welcome to this forum.

Answer (score 5):

Not simultaneously, but it's simple to do it manually by using guides, the snapping option: *Snap Nodes Paths and Handles*, and by holding down CTRL as you click and drag the Bézier handles to constrain the angle.

[image]

There is also a rather convoluted way to make symmetrical shapes automatically. It's probably too complex for your particular scenario, but certainly useful for more complex symmetry.

You can create a half ellipse, clone it, reflect it, move into position. Then the edits made to the clone source will update automatically in the reflected clone.

[image]

Comment: The guides seem like an okay work around for my case, but why does it have to be complex to do more complex shapes? This seems like it'd be very simple to implement a couple toggles or modes for when adjusting nodes.

Comment: Remember, Inkscape is essentially an SVG editor. If such features are not implemented in the SVG standards, then most often it will not appear in Inkscape.  Clones are a part of the SVG standard already.

Comment: SVGs are graphics, right? So then graphic designers would be using Inkscape. And graphic designers would very likely use symmetry tools, especially in vector images. So yes, I would expect these tools to be in Inkscape. It's a shame that they aren't, since this is not the first time I've had this issue. This is just what got me to go, "There has to be an easier way!"

Comment: I don't think you understand what I'm saying.  The Inkscape developers don't control SVG standards, they try to work within in them, so that Inkscape can produce SVGs which can be rendered properly in browsers which support these standards.  Actually SVGs are not really graphics as such, they are actually code (a kind of XML in fact), somewhat like HTML.

Comment: In SVG, clones are certainly the way to go for complex symmetry, and not just bilateral symmetry.  I've used it to create complex designs [like this example here](https://imgur.com/a/s1svl4C).  Clones also help keep file sizes smaller so they render quicker - so they serve more than one purpose.

Comment: SVG stands for Standard Vector Graphic, doesn't it? I understand that vectors not actually graphics but rather a series of instructions to create graphics, but it also seems reasonable to me to allow multiple nodes to be adjusted at once with a few simple modes. It's all just applying the same or adjusted math to multiple nodes. Not every project needs clones. I use Inkscape to make maps for my D&D group. I often want to make symmetrical shapes for those maps, but I don't need my whole design to be symmetrical.

Comment: In fact, most of the time I don't want my whole design to be symmetrical and I want to make non-symmetrical adjustments after making it symmetrical. This is why clones aren't ideal for me at all and a few nodal adjustment tools would benefit me greatly.

Comment: You can unlink a clone after using it initially, then you can edit the paths independently afterwards. Juancho mentions this in his answer at the second last paragraph.

Comment: Yeah but I, like many others, am quite fickle and might decide to make symmetric changes again, or possibly even non-symmetric changes that would simply be easier if I could adjust multiple nodes at once like making waves or loops along a complex path. All of this seems so simple to me and like it should have been implemented already for the user's sake.

Comment: Then you can keep an unedited copy of the clone for that purpose, even create a new clone. There are already ways to use clones to make waves and loops along a complex path. Inkscape already has *Pattern Along a Path* functionality.

Comment: @Voila Its not quite easy as that. Adding a lot of indirect manipulation in a software makes it harder to master. And developing such a system is in fact quite hard. So not only will it make things harder to use and learn making it work the right way is surprisingly tricky. Now then the question is if i want to make rotation symmetry or multi symmetry or anti symmetry those are valid needs also, so at th end of the day you can continue the complaint. Something to be said about keeping things easy. But inkscape is open source you go and do it. Oh wait it is already done, but needlessly hard QED

Answer (score 4):

My technique is to draw only half of the shape, and use a clone for the other half. This way you can edit the original half and the clone will update accordingly:

[image]

1. First create your ellipse and convert to path.
2. Check your [snapping options](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Snapping.html#Snapping-Guide) so you can easily overlap a rectangle over the left half.
3. Select both objects and *Path -> Difference*.
4. Edit the path to remove any unwanted segments.
5. Clone your half shape (<kbd>Alt-D</kbd>), and flip the clone horizontally (<kbd>H</kbd>).
6. Move the clone so it snaps in place.
7. Now you can edit your original path and the clone should follow.

If, when finished, you want to convert the whole thing into a single path, you can select the clone, then *Edit -> Clone -> Unlink*, then combine the two paths into one, and optionally check for resulting double nodes with the path tool.

Another technique is to use a *path effect* called mirror symmetry, which gives more flexibility but is trickier to use.

Comment: Isn't there a simpler way? That's very complex for something that I would expect to be simple and easy.

Answer (score 0):

Would the Mirror Live Path effect do what you need?

[image]